# How to install JDK on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I downloaded the Java Development Kit from Oracle web site. Since it came as a tar.gz file I have no idea how to install it. Please help me to install it on my Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: There is a lot of direct instructions on web how to install jdk for ubuntu. Just google it.

Comment: Read "READ ME" file.

Answer (score -1):

tar.gz is an archive file.  Extract it and follow instructions, there should be readme/install file with description what you should do.